# what's the difference between using MMMM and MMMMM to extract the month's name using SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, date, format

I guess the answer is none. If I use 4 or more "M" the result is the same.

```
public static void main (String[] args) 
{
    for (int monthNum = 1; monthNum <= 12; monthNum++) 
    {
        String month = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM", Locale.US)
                          .format (new Date (1, monthNum, 2000));

        String month2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMM", Locale.US)
                          .format (new Date (1, monthNum, 2000));

        if (month.equals(month2)) 
              continue;

        throw new RuntimeException ("");
    }
}
```

Ends successfully.

However I don't understand why the [examples](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) in `SimpleDateFormat` use specifically 5 'M' instead of 4 or any other number >=4. The only explanation about the result given a number of 'M' in the pattern string is:

> Month: If the number of pattern letters is 3 or more, the month is
>   interpreted as text; otherwise, it is interpreted as a number.

Does it make any difference then? Why wouldn't it be better documented?

Comment: How would you improve it?  You wanted them to document what `3 or more` meant?

Comment: The documentation is perfectly clear. There's only a single example that uses `MMMMM`.

Comment: 3 gives a shortened version, for example. How would you know for sure that 4 yields the same result as any other larger number. I agree is kind of intuitively obvious, but not conclusive.

Comment: One of them sounds like the date is more tasty!

Comment: for Android, according to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

_Five-count patterns (such as "MMMMM") used for the shortest non-numeric representation of a field were introduced in Android 4.3 (Jelly Bean MR2, API level 18)._

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Look once again at the javadoc piece which you quoted:

> **Month**: If the number of pattern letters is 3 or more, the month is interpreted as [text](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#text); otherwise, it is interpreted as a [number](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#number).

Click the link behind "text" in the documentation. It brings you back to the previous point:

> **Text**: For formatting, if the number of pattern letters is 4 or more, the full form is used; otherwise a short or abbreviated form is used if available. For parsing, both forms are accepted, independent of the number of pattern letters.

Thus, if it's 4 letters or more, then the full form is used, otherwise the short form is used. The example with 5 letters fits in the category "4 letters or more".